# What are my options (if any) for MySQL with Python 3?

Tags: python, mysql

I recently starting playing around with the new features of Python 3.1 and porting one of my 2.6 apps.  I was surprised to find that MySQLdb does not yet support any of the 3.x versions of Python.  My app uses MySQL extensively, so, as you can imagine, I didn't get too far!

What are my options (if any) for working with MySQL and Python 3.1?  I've been out of the Python 3k loop, but cursory search did not yield any evidence of a release date for 3.1 support in MySQLdb or any other alternatives.

Comment: It's quite sad that there are so many good extensions for Python out there but all those won't update for Python 3 :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[mypysql](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mypysql/) doesn't follow the Python DB API standard, but does support Mysql and Python 3.

Comment: Thanks for the info, Alex!  I had a chance to catch you at OSCON this year (Abstraction Maintenance) and really enjoyed the talk.  I'll probably stick with 2.6 for now with an eye towards MySQL support that follows the Python DB API standard.

Comment: @jonstjohn, yes, Py2 still gives you more choice in add-ons (and btw, glad you liked my talk -- it's also online at http://us.pycon.org/2009/conference/schedule/event/75/ ).

Answer (score 0):

You could use `pymysql`. "The goal of PyMySQL is to be a drop-in replacement for MySQLdb". Check the docs [here](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL).

> pip install mysqlclient pymysql

Once these libraries are installed, just add the lines in your project wherever `MySQLdb` is used.

> import pymysql
>
> pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()